# when we declare a variable final and instantiate it without giving it a specific value(wuffle)

Tags: final, non-static

Is the default value final(wuffle = 0) or we can change it(wuffle =21)?

```
class Foof{

final int x=0;
final int wuffle; //IT GETS A DEFAULT VALUE

Foof(){

wuffle = 21; // as it is marked final we should't be able to change its value

       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you declare final variable, it is still undefined. if you make it final and you don't have provided definition your code won't compile